# How did Jun John Sakurai die?

Tags: biographical-details, physicists, death

How did theoretical physicist Jun John Sakurai die? The only result from extensive googling is that he died "suddenly" while working at CERN. Does anyone know anything more specific?

Comment: Nothing definitive is known. Max Sang:"*Extremely unlikely to have been cancer. He was working on a book and working at CERN at the time. Whatever it was, it was sudden and unexpected which would suggest a stroke or heart attack. Neither are unknown at 49, sadly*". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AJ._J._Sakurai

Comment: williamg did not give the sources that he googled and my suggestions were simply that, suggestions of sources that he might try for additional information. My reference to the original hard copy issue was to check and see if his name and job might have been mentioned for someone not familiar with him. His name and job were not listed. AS

Comment: I found same question, but the answer was same. https://www.zhihu.com/question/22699026

Answer (score 3):

J.J Sakurai died from aneurysm in his rented flat in France next to CERN, which he was visiting. His body was discovered on Monday, November 1, 1982, the official date of his death, when he didn't show up in CERN but his death probably occurred the preceding Friday evening.

Comment: This answer would benefit from citing sources.

Comment: @njuffa, I was about to post the aneurysm reference citation that appears in his Wikipedia entry, but discovered that it points to *this* answer.  According to modern logic, that proves that it must be true.

Comment: See Daniel Sterneheimer's "*Fond memories of Julian and Clarice, especially involving Moshe Flato and Noriko Sakurai*". In particular, see page 279 of the "Proceedings Of The Julian Schwinger Centennial Conference" in which this paper is published.  I'll update the wikipedia article to use this as the citation rather than the HSM link (which doesn't meet the WP:RS guideline).

Comment: @RayButterworth https://xkcd.com/978/